# How to large file upload in s3 bucket using Laravel

Tags: php, amazon-s3

We have a laravel project and We have video functionality. Using the laravel project we are uploading videos in s3 bucket.

We are uploading video 50MB to 80MB In the s3 bucket but getting an error of **Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded the error.**

We have changed the below value of the PHP .ini file.

1. upload_max_filesize
2. post_max_size
3. max_input_time
4. max_execution_time

Also, we have used the **TimeOut** parameter in Ajax Request.

But Still, we have the same issue.

Does anyone has any suggestions or any solution then please help with it.

Thanks a lot.